# Postgres SQL slow when using OR statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query that take 12 seconds (journal table 1.2m rows), the root cause is below

```
select 1
from
   myTable myTable
   join myJournal Journal on (Journal.status=0 and myTable.id = Journal.myTableId)
   join arrival Arrival on (myTable.id = Arrival.myTableId)
   join calc Calc on (myTable.id = Calculated.myTableId)
   join ms ms on (Parent.id = ms.myTableId)   
   join perf Perf on (myTable.id = Perf.myTableId)
   join ref Ref on (myTable.id = Ref.myTableId)
where
    ((myTable.name like 'cheese%' or 
     Journal.algorithm like 'cheese%' or --if this is removed, its fine <1sec
     myTable.client like 'cheese%' or 
     myTable.something like 'cheese%'))
```

However the journal table performs ok. Doing

```
select * from myJournal where algorithm like 'cheese%' --takes < 1 sec.
```

The query also performs fine, if I remove four of the joins (that are not used in the where clause).

When I join on more than 3 tables the performance degrades dramatically/exponentially.

Comment: perhaps you may need a composite index on `Journal(myTableId,status)`.

Comment: The expression `ilike '%cheese%'` _cannot_ use an index as far as I know.  If you have this sort of need, look into using full text search.  Otherwise, if you want to use an index, make sure you are using the entire column or only a prefix, but not a suffix.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok thanks, but that doesn't fully explain the slowness ?  As that query on its own is fast

Comment: Well, you are adding more restrictions, which means it will take longer.  To be clear here, your "OK" query is probably not using an index.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah, I understand that. I've edited my question, the problem still remains

Comment: I am running out of steam, but again I will state that your query probably won't use an index.  If you really need this to run fast, then focus on changing your table structure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the presence or absence of an index isn't the problem, imo. Edited, like with wildcard at end uses index.

Comment: Well now you've completely changed the query.  In this case, we might able to use an index.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the query has changed, but the problem is exactly the same. We can see that one query on the journal table is not slow on its own, but when combined in an OR it causes a problem.  As I said, the presence of absence of an index is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Please include the full select clause on the first query, if you want to get some suggestions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen which fields are returned does not effect the performance of the query, I can simply do select 1, and it performs poorly

Comment: Right...so I am trying to come up with an index suggestion which might make the query run quickly.  But I need to know exactly which columns you want to select.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as I said, simply select 1 with the included from and where performs poorly.  The returned fields have no significant effect.

Comment: I attempted an answer below, give it a shot and let us know if it worked.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen fyi SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = off; fixes my prob

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: `ilike '%cheese%'` _can_ use an index - just not a BTree index. But it can use a [trigram](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good stuff, thanks for that comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by writing the query as:

```
select 1
from myTable t join
     myJournal j
     on t.id = j.myTableId
where j.status = 0 and
      (t.name like 'cheese%' or 
       j.algorithm like 'cheese%' or 
       t.client like 'cheese%' or 
       t.something like 'cheese%'
      )
```

Then the optimal indexes for this are probably `myJournal(status, myTableId, algorithm)` and `myTable(id, name, client, something)`.

These indexes are primarily for the `join` and the first filter condition.  They won't help much with the string comparisons.  But, those are hard to optimize for due to the `or` conditions.

Comment: so I thought my question was all the relevant info, but there are other joins not used in the where.  When I removed the other joins, but keep the slow bit int question, the perfromance improves dramatically, as much as removing that one or statement.  Am I hitting some postgres threshold for joining ?

Comment: lol, I didn't downvote.   So it turns out, if I join on more than 3 tables the performance degrades dramatically. Maybe I am hitting some postgres internal limit/threshold

Comment: @NimChimpsky . . . First, you cannot really optimize the `OR` comparisons on strings; both the `OR` and the strings impede that (unless Postgres has a fancy mechanism for this).  Second, you can possibly optimize the `JOIN`s.  Third, you have to be careful when looking at results to measure durations.  That could be a function of how quickly the first results are returned rather than all the results.

Comment: fyi SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = off; fixes the problem

Comment: @NimChimpsky . . . Interesting.  The complex `where` clause is causing Postgres to switch to a nested loop join.  That sounds like a bug in the optimizer to me.